# How can I store a very very large number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What if I want to store a very very large number and then display it. For example factorial of 200.

**How can I do this using JavaScript?**

I tried the normal way and the result is null or infinity.

```js
function fact(input) {
    if(input == 0) {
        return 1;
        }
    return input * fact(input-1);
}
var result = fact(171);
console.log(result);
```

[image]

I tried in normal way and the result is infinity or null.
It seems JavaScript can generate Factorial up to 170.

[image]

Look at this picture. This calculator seems able to do it.

Comment: [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is supported by Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The BigInt numeric type is going to be implemented in the future of JavaScript, [the proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bigint) is on Stage 3 on the ECMAScript standardization process and it's being supported by [major browsers now](https://v8.dev/features/bigint).

You can use either the `BigInt` constructor or the numeric literal by appending an `n` at the end of the number.

In older environments you can use [a polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigint-polyfill).

```js
function fact(input) {
    if(input == 0n) {
        return 1n;
    }
    return input * fact(input-1n);
}

const result = fact(171n);

console.log(String(result));
```

Comment: Thanks. You really helped me out. I just wanted to know that. Now I know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript based BigInteger library. There are many to choose from. But i recommend this one https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

Example:

```
var num = bigInt("9187239176928376598273465972639458726934756929837450")
.plus("78634075162394756297465927364597263489756289346592");
```